# live streaming videos

Tags: video-streaming

how can i load live streaming videos from webcam  to database(sqlserver 2005) and also how can i retrived it from database remotelocations and displayed these videos as link

Answer (score 0):

You can put videos on a fileshare or media server and then reference the URI or path to allow them to be loaded from wherever they are needed.  IE: put the file on a webserver and you end up with the url http://someServer/media/video01932.avi.  In the database you have a row that is ID: 1932 Name: awesome video URL: http://someserver/media/video01932.avi which then gets retreived over http.  Alternatively, if you are looking for truly live storage, you could use IceCast, RTSP, Apple Streaming Server and I think Microsoft has a media streaming server out there and then put the URI in the database, for example rtsp://12.15.89.231:124/

Comment: how can i displayed these videos in one website as link